# Zendesk Talk Dashboard for IVR's

Tags: zendesk

I need some advice and pointers on how to go about creating a dashboard that shows which Zendesk talk lines have IVR's enabled on them to keep better track of active IVR's. Another idea would be to have notifications go out via email when an IVR has been enabled for a specific amount of time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Questions on this site should be specific. Please show what you have tried, and be specific about where exactly you get stuck in creating a dashboard that meets your needs.